# I use this code to produce a triangle arrow and I make some changes to the size of the triangle, why doesn't it compile successfully?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I use this code to produce a triangle arrow and I make some changes to the size of the triangle, why doesn't it compile successfully?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[minimum height=1.5mm]}]
(0,2) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minimum height` is not a valid key for the `Triangle` arrow tip, and the package informs this; your code produces the error message

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key 'minimum height', to which you p
assed '1.5mm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Perhaps you want `length`, `width`, or `scale`?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[length=0.5cm]}]
(0,1) -- (1,1);
\draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[width=1.5cm]}]
(0,-0.5) -- (1,-0.5);
\draw[green,arrows={-Triangle[scale=3]}]
(0,-2) -- (2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The valid keys for the Triangle arrow tip can be found on page 211 of the manual.